# splice/merge/combine videos from array in Swift 5

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, swift5, nsurl

I'm new to the AVFoundation part of swift. I am trying to splice multiple videos (URL's) into one video. (Splice meaning have one video play after another, in the order of the array) I have seen several threads on this but they're all outdated and no longer work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var outputUrl: URL! //video goes here after recording
var videoArray = [URL]() 

//after recording,
videoArray.append(outputUrl)

func splice() {
// I need help with this part;
 //splice each entry in videoArray
}

var splicedVideo: URL! //<-- I need to save the composition to this URL
```

Sorry if this question isn't what you're used to seeing; I'm trying to be as specific as possible but I'm not sure where to start.  Can someone help me write this function or point me to a thread with one?